# Doppler effect and frame of reference

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames, doppler-effect

We know that in an inertial frame we can never tell if the frame is really at rest or moving with constant velocity but can’t we check if there is a change in frequency by a sound emitted by the frame to see if it’s moving or really at rest?

If I got something wrong forgive me. My physics fundamentals are not really up to the mark.

Answer (score 2):

> can’t we check if there is a change in frequency by a sound emitted by the frame to see if it’s moving or really at rest?

No. For example, if you do this experiment in a jet you will get zero Doppler shift regardless of if you are parked at the gate, taxiing on the ground, or at full speed in the air. This experiment measures your speed relative to air through which the sound moves. It does not measure speed in an absolute sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare your *relative* motion to other things that are not co-moving with you, via the doppler effect you mentioned or any number of ways. But you using only your local surroundings (e.g. inside the plane's walls with no windows) you cannot do an experiment that would reveal your own motion.